# Are OS threads tied to thread_num in different OpenMP parallel regions?

Tags: openmp

If I have multiple parallel regions, would same thread be used for given thread index (returned by `omp_get_thread_num()`) in those parallel regions?

Comment: AFAIK it os not imposed by the standard, so it would be safe to assume that no

Comment: Although the standard says that this is undefined, in reality it is likely normally to be true. That is because the standard *does* talk about the preservation of static thread-local state, so if the runtime uses underlying thread mechanisms for that, then the binding of OS thread to OpenMP thread-id follows. So do not rely on it for correctness, but from a performance POV you can reasonably assume it to be true. (Of course, if you use recent OpenMP features for destroying threads `omp_pause_resource` https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu159.html#x202-2350003.6.1 all bets are off)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **undefined** by the OpenMP standard (version 5.1), **except for the primary thread** (master thread) encountering the two sections (assuming they are encountered by the same thread in your application):

> The thread that encountered the `parallel` construct becomes the primary thread of the new team, with a thread number of zero for the duration of the new `parallel` region.

Note that the this could not be true if you use *untied tasks* in your parallel section:

> The thread number may change during the execution of an untied task. The value returned by `omp_get_thread_num` is not generally useful during the execution of such a task region.